# Move excel files from OneDrive to SharePoint (vba)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Been using this vba for years for moving files from one folder/location to another:

```
Sub MoveFilesNewLocation()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim DD, FP, TP As String

    DD = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")           
    FP = "C:\Users\myid\OneDrive - Myid\Mine dokumenter\OLAttachments\"    
    'TP = "C:\Users\myid\OneDrive - Myid\Mine dokumenter\MyDownload\"   '(this TP works just fine) 
    TP = "https://myjob.sharepoint.com/sites/FAS/Plan/2022/Dash/Store/" '(this TP = "Run-time error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument)
    
    
Name FP & "MyExcelFileNo1.xls" As TP & "MyExcelFileNo1.xls"
Name FP & "MyExcelFileNo2.xls" As TP & "MyExcelFileNo2.xls"
Name FP & "MyExcelFileNo3.xls" As TP & "MyExcelFileNo3.xls"
Name FP & "MyExcelFileNo4.xls" As TP & "MyExcelFileNo4.xls"
Name FP & "MyExcelFileNo5.xls" As TP & "MyExcelFileNo5.xls"


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But now I need to move files from my OneDrive and to a SharePoint-adress. I've changed my "TP" (to path) to SharePoint-adress, but I get a run-time error. No files moved.
What's the issue here? I can easily move the same files manually by drag them from browser and drop them into SharePoint location...

Comment: You can't use `Name` with an http path.  You'd need to map a folder or sync that folder on your local machine and copy the files to the synced location.  Lots of fun challenges moving to onedrive/sharepoint !

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Seems like my job's shift to OneDrive and SharePoint doesn't give me any benefits... :-)